# I want to detect a laser spot(circle) in different kinds of light conditions

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

this code works, but when the webcam is facing an area that has light it also recognizes it as a laser pointer. What i want for help is to eliminate those noise and only recognize the laser pointer.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP6GN.png) This picture shows how it looks like in the mask but, no light conditions yet. Here is my code so far:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, main = cap.read()

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(main, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(main, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        lower_laserdot = np.array([0, 0, 255]) 
        upper_laserdot = np.array([255, 255, 255])

        threshold = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_laserdot, upper_laserdot)
        circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 700, param1 
= 50, param2 = 30, minRadius = 0, maxRadius = 0)

        threshcopy = threshold.copy()
        _, find, _ = cv2.findContours(threshcopy, cv2.RETR_LIST, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

        maxarea = 1
        bestcnt = 1

        for cnt in find:
            area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
            if area > maxarea:
                maxarea = area
                bestcnt = cnt

        M = cv2.moments(bestcnt)
        x, y = int(M['m10']/M['m00']), int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

        if circles is not None:
            circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
            for(cx,cy,r) in circles:
                if x > 0 or y > 0:
                    print('A laser dot has been detected')
        cv2.imshow('mask', threshold)
        rs = cv2.resize(main, (1365, 730))
        cv2.imshow('main', rs)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing it is red dot, filter only red hues (e.g. Hue <25 and Hue>230). You can also increase contrast in the image, because laser is most likely highest intensity color in the pic.

Comment: how do i do that exacyly?

Comment: Convert image BGR2HSV https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html. Create similar sized mask. If H value in hsv numpy array is <25 or >230, set corresponding bit in mask numpy array as 1 or 255 depending on color depth of the mask you created.

Comment: No no. I mean how to increase the contrast of an image?